# PHP XPath selecting last matching element

Tags: php, xpath

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PHP SimpleXML. How to get the last item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295112/php-simplexml-how-to-get-the-last-item)
>   [XSLT Select all nodes containing a specific substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672997/xslt-select-all-nodes-containing-a-specific-substring)

I need to find the contents of the last span element with a class of 'myClass'. I've tried various combinations but can't find the answer.

```
//span[@class='myPrice' and position()=last()]
```

This returns all the elements with class 'myClass', I'm guessing this is because each found element is the last at the time of processing - but I just need the actual last matching element.

Comment: @fabrik: I think not. This would be more proper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672997/xslt-select-all-nodes-containing-a-specific-substring . It's not last but first and does not have `php` tag...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You have to mark for the processor that you want to treat `//span[@class='myPrice']` as the current set and then apply the predicate position()=last() to that set.

```
(//span[@class='myPrice'])[last()]
```

e.g.

```
<?php
$doc = getDoc();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach( $xpath->query("(//span[@class='myPrice'])[last()]") as $n ) {
  echo $n->nodeValue, "\n";
}


function getDoc() {
  $doc = new DOMDOcument;
  $doc->loadxml( <<< eox
<foo>
  <span class="myPrice">1</span>
  <span class="yourPrice">0</span>
  <bar>
    <span class="myPrice">4</span>
    <span class="yourPrice">99</span>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <span class="myPrice">9</span>
  </bar>
</foo>
eox
  );
  return $doc;
}
```

Comment: How do I exclude last row? actually I want to exclude last two rows from resultset. Is that possible with one `xpath` expression?

Answer (score 8):

The expression you used means "select every span element provided that (a) it has `@class='myprice'`, and (b) it is the last child of its parent. There are two errors:

(1) you need to apply the filter `[position()=last()]` after filtering by @class, rather than applying it to all span elements

(2) an expression of the form `//span[last()]` means `/descendant-or-self::*/(child::span[last()])` which selects the last child span of every element. You need to use parentheses to change the precedence:  `(//span)[last()]`.

So the expression becomes `(//span[@class='myPrice'])[last()]` as given by VolkerK.