# Get last li content Xpath php

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I have next html:

```
<ul class="pages">
<li class="page-1 active"><a data-page="1" href="/sold?page=1">1</a></li>
<li class="page-2"><a data-page="2" href="/sold?page=2">2</a></li>
<li class="page-3"><a data-page="3" href="/sold?page=3">3</a></li>
<li>...</li>
<li class="page-975"><a data-page="975" href="/sold?page=975">975</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to get the last li's text which contains the number of the last page (in my example it is 975) with help of Xpath.

I've tried something like:

```
$page_count = $xpath->query(".//ul[@class='pages']/li/a[last()]/text()")->item(0)->textContent;
```

but it doesn't work.

what would be the correct query to get last li's text?

Comment: `li/a[last()]` fetches all the lies, then the last `<a>` inside that `<li>`. you'd want `li[last()]/a`

Comment: tried but getting "Trying to get property of non-object" notice on line with query

Comment: What about this ? > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537129/php-xpath-selecting-last-matching-element

Comment: @TareqAl-Zubaidi I've seen that one, but unfortunatelly the class of the last li element is unknown since it will be different each time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
$page_count = $xpath->query(".//ul[@class='pages']/li[last()]/a/text()")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

first:  you need to grab the last `li` and then the text of its `a`-element

Your version basically searches all the `li`-elements and within them searches for the last `a`-element (they only have one) and then their text attribute. So you basically got a list of all the texts.

second: try `nodeValue` instead of `textContent`

Comment: Getting "Trying to get property of non-object" notice on line with code

Comment: what is the full query code (starting with $page_count =)?

Comment: try nodeValue instead of textContent (but I'm just guessing, I'm not a php expert =(

Comment: Ok, first code (on top) works, second version returns "1"

Comment: edit your answer to include top code in whole code and I will accept :) Thank so much for helping me out!

Comment: haha, thanks man, good eye, second code was meant to be the same as the first one but with nodeValue attached -> edited my answer