# How to set last index key

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I would like to find out how I can set the last index key (without knowing what it is in advance) in the following code that fetches a price from a SIMPLEXML response:

```
$product_price = $CATEGORIES->PRODUCTS->PRICES->PRICE[0]->AMOUNT;
```

There may be more than 1 price, so at times there are 3, at times 5 etc. But I would only like to get the last one, so the key in `PRICE[0]` needs to dynamically fetch the last one.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: `$product_price = $CATEGORIES->PRODUCTS->PRICES->PRICE[count($CATEGORIES->PRODUCTS->PRICES->PRICE)-1]->AMOUNT;`

Comment: @Anant uhgg, thats ugly

Comment: code which is hard to read, which isnt well formated.

Comment: Not a dupe as this question is about a PHP array and this answer is about how to get it using Xpath http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537129/php-xpath-selecting-last-matching-element

Answer (score 2):

You can you use [`end()`](http://php.net/end) to get last element in array.

```
$prices = $CATEGORIES->PRODUCTS->PRICES;
$last_price = end($prices);
$amount = $last_price->AMOUNT;
```

Comment: Also `$product_price =  end($CATEGORIES->PRODUCTS->PRICES->PRICE)->AMOUNT;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Like this:

```
$array = array('a','b','c');

// This get the value and remove it from the end of the array
$test1 = array_pop($array);

// This will only get the value from the array
$array[] = $test2 = array_pop($array);

var_dump($test1); // "c"
var_dump($test2); // "b"
var_dump($array); // array('a', 'b')
```

Comment: It may not be an issue but it actually removes it from the array, so if you need the array later then its not ideal.

Comment: See $test2 - although your not completely off, even in the case of $test2 if the original value is passed by reference or a reference itself, then the reference is lost.